# Best practise to send an fb access_token from an iOS app to a server

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, uri, facebook-ios-sdk

Once a user has been logged in through FB login on my iOS app, I want to be able to retrieve the access_token given by Fb on my server (nodeJS) to perform API Graph Fb call. 
What is the best the way to get this access_token on my server ?
Maybe with uri_redirect but I haven't found how to use it with SDK FB login.

Thanks a lot,

GE

Comment: You need to make a URL request, POST or GET to your server with that token

Comment: https://code.bradymower.com/swift-3-apis-network-requests-json-getting-the-data-4aaae8a5efc0

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer :) Using uri_redirect from FB oauth wouldn't be more secure ? I mean the client won't know the access_token and only server will perform api calls adding also the secret_appId from fb ?

Comment: when using the ios fbsdk, you (the app) sort-of act as the redirect. this is because the fbsdk is concieved as a gateway to the Facebook Graph API, meaning it serves as more than just an authentification framework. This is so that devs could technically build out apps with facebook without a cloud back-end, and run front-end only apps. So when a user authenticates, you can access what the user's given you permission to use right in the app, or you can extract the token from the sdk, and send it to your back-end to do other things there too. it's up to you really.

Comment: for example, in an app i'm working on, when the user creates an account with facebook, i get the token right away, send it to my back end which extracts basic info to create the account. Then, when my server gives my app a positive response, the app extracts the user's profile picture url from the SDK, the app then downloads that picture, i then upload it to an image delivery service i use. From that, I get the saved image's url, and send that url to be saved in my back-end's database. This saves me the bandwidth of having to upload pictures through my servers. saves me $ in the end.

Comment: That's just an example of how your app can accomplish more for your back-end with the SDK. You used to have to do this through servers, but now Facebook's SDK can be useful like this right in the front-end

Comment: Thanks @murphguy